# Apple ID has been disable , how to enable and reset password?

Tags: apple-id

I'm struggling on how to enable Apple ID and reset password. I open itune and try to sign in and it pops up this message:

[image]

Whne i click Reset, it leads to a website where i put my apple id (email address which is my gmail) then click Next then there're 2 options which i chose to send to my email. 
I've tried that so many times but never recieved any email from apple for me to reset the password.

Anyone please help! I've check the spams and everything but nothing at all from apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest way, shoot a mail to the Apple support team.

They will revert back to you asking a couple of personal information questions, and once they are convinced you are the rightful owner of the account, they can enable/unlock your account.

Comment: What's the apple email for support?

Comment: What mail address is the "Apple support team" and does it change for accounts in different countries?

Answer (score 3):

All you do is go to https://iforgot.apple.com and you can go through several paths to attempt to reset your password.